# MSBuild. Folders with specific characters

Tags: msbuild

I'd like to build some projects of the solution with MSBuild. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019) says to replace `.` with `_` in project names, and it does work for project names, yet doesn't work for folder names:

`msbuild Solution.sln /t:"Folder\Project1_Name"` - Works for `Folder\Project1.Name.csproj`

`msbuild Solution.sln /t:"Folder.Name\Project2"` - Doesn't work for `Folder.Name\Project2.Name.csproj`

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: The name "Folder.Name\Project2" contains an invalid character ".".
```

`msbuild Solution.sln /t:"Folder_Name\Project2_Name"` - Doesn't work for `Folder.Name\Project2.Name.csproj`

```
error MSB4057: The target "Folder_Name\Project2_Name" does not exist in the project.
```

Comment: What is the solution folder name (within the sln file) in that case? This may be different than the folder name on disk.

Comment: It's in root directory, no special characters. Here is the structure: \Solution.sln, \Folder\Project1.Name.csproj, Folder.Name\Project2.Name.csproj.